# using custom page

Tags: theme-development

i have a trouble with wordpress custom pages when i set page-{slug}.php, It is not working and it shows index's contents. It is used to work until i updated the wordpress version 4.9.2 to 4.9.4

I did reinstall wordpress 4.9.2 and tried it again. It is still not working

How can i solve it.

index.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="container">
<?php masterslider(2); ?>

</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

page-{slug}.php

```
<?php get_header("cpt"); ?>

<div class="container">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
the_content();
endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>

 <div class="row">
    <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'cpt', 'posts_per_page' => 15 ) ); ?>
    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <li class="nolist"> <div class="posts">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">



    <!--Card content-->
<div class="card" >
<!---thumbnails--->

                     <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php
                         // Must be inside a loop.

                        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                            the_post_thumbnail();
                        }
                         else {
                             echo '<img class="img-fluid" src="' . get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) 
                                    . '/img/ocg.jpg" class="img-responsive" />';
                         }
                      ?></a>
                      <!---- thumbnails end--->

  <div class="card-body">
      <h6 class="card-title"><a  href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> </a></h6>
<hr>
      <div class="text-center">
          <a  href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> read</a>
      </div>

  </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-center">
    <?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) ; ?> 
    </div>
</div>


<?php endwhile; ?></div>
    </div></li></div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I`m not sure, but this [case](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/updated-to-4-9-wont-detect-page-template/) can call same issue. And in [this code](https://github.com/connorlacombe/WP-Clear-File-Cache)
 answeer is present. I had same problem earlier.

Comment: i did it but still not works. i returned 4.8 version but still not works.